# How do I modify an existing database table (add/remove columns) with PetaPOCO (Umbraco 6, MVC)

Tags: c#, sql, umbraco, petapoco, umbraco6

I have an Umbraco CMS application with some custom functionality for which I use PetaPOCO to store data in my database.
I created my POCO and an Umbraco event that fires on application startup to create the table if it does not exist:

```
public class RegisterEvents : ApplicationEventHandler
{
    //This happens everytime the Umbraco Application starts
    protected override void ApplicationStarted(UmbracoApplicationBase umbracoApplication, ApplicationContext applicationContext)
    {
        //Get the Umbraco Database context
        var db = applicationContext.DatabaseContext.Database;

        //Check if the DB table does NOT exist
        if (!db.TableExist("MyTable"))
        {
            //Create DB table - and set overwrite to false
            db.CreateTable<MyPetaPOCO>(false);
        }
    }
}
```

How do I modify the existing database (I want to add a column) without direct access to the database? I need to use code because the host doesn't provide access yet. I think I should be able to do this in this ApplicationStarted override event but I do not know how.

**Edit**

Should I use somethingl [Fluent Migrator](http://nugetmusthaves.com/Package/FluentMigrator)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using PetaPoco, you could use the `db.Execute("alter table ...")` but then you would need to have sufficient access rights to execute a DDL statement like that.

Also I would run this within a PetaPoco transaction too, as it's good practice.

Finally, if you were running this at Application_Start (which is fine) you would need to perform a check to ensure that the column didn't already exist.

Comment: Digby, wow, that execute method is hidden pretty good in the PetaPOCO documentation (just a few lines between others that have far more documentation). Thanks, will try your solution. Drink one of your own brews for this one please ;), cheers.

Answer (score 8):

If this is a package or something that you are deploying (or are having others consume), you should create a migration and run it in your ApplicationStarted method.

https://cultiv.nl/blog/using-umbraco-migrations-to-deploy-changes/

Example from the above article:

In order to add a column to an existing PetaPOCO DB:

**Create a migration class that derives from MigrationBase:**

```
[Migration("1.0.1", 1, "YourTableName")]
  public class AddNewColumnToTable : MigrationBase
  {
    public AddNewColumnToTable(ISqlSyntaxProvider sqlSyntax, ILogger logger) 
      : base(sqlSyntax, logger)
    { }

    public override void Up()
    {
      Alter.Table("YourTableName").AddColumn("ColumnToAdd").AsString().Nullable();
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
      Delete.Column("ColumnToAdd").FromTable("YourTableName");
    }
  }
```

**Update your `ApplicationStarted` with logic to run the migration:**

```
  public class MyApplication : ApplicationEventHandler
  {
    protected override void ApplicationStarted(UmbracoApplicationBase umbracoApplication, ApplicationContext applicationContext)
    {
      HandleStatisticsMigration();
    }

    private static void HandleStatisticsMigration()
    {
      const string productName = "YourTableName";
      var currentVersion = new SemVersion(0, 0, 0);

      // get all migrations for "YourTableName" already executed
      var migrations = ApplicationContext.Current.Services.MigrationEntryService.GetAll(productName);

     // get the latest migration for "YourTableName" executed
     var latestMigration = migrations.OrderByDescending(x => x.Version).FirstOrDefault();

     if (latestMigration != null)
       currentVersion = latestMigration.Version;

     var targetVersion = new SemVersion(1, 0, 1);
     if (targetVersion == currentVersion)
       return;

     var migrationsRunner = new MigrationRunner(
       ApplicationContext.Current.Services.MigrationEntryService,
       ApplicationContext.Current.ProfilingLogger.Logger,
       currentVersion,
       targetVersion,
       productName);

     try
     {
       migrationsRunner.Execute(UmbracoContext.Current.Application.DatabaseContext.Database);
     }
     catch (Exception e)
     {
       LogHelper.Error<MyApplication>("Error running YourTableName migration", e);
     }
   }
 }
```

Note that the target version should match the version you set in your `Migration` class attribute (in this example, 1.0.1)

As you make updates and add new functionality to your application or plugin, you create new migrations (if needed), and update your target version.